# How do I group date by month using pd.Grouper?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, pandas-groupby

I've searched stackoverflow to find out how to group DateTime by month and for some reason I keep receiving this error, even after I pass the dataframe through `pd.to.datetime`

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or
>   PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))
```

When I pull the datatype for `df['Date']` it shows `dtype: datetime64[ns]` Any, ideas why I keep getting this error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason is simple: you didn't pass a groupby key to `groupby`.

What you want is to group the entire dataframe by the month values of the contents of `df['Date']`.

However, what `df['Date'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))` actually does is first extract a `pd.Series` from the DataFrame's `Date` column. Then, it attempts to perform a groupby *on that `Series`*; without a specified key, it defaults to attempting to group by the index, which is of course numeric.

This will work:

`df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'))`

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with the frequency being both month and year?