# Is there a way to group the values in a monthly format, using datetime64 format?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, python-itertools

I have tried using `groupby`, however, the date format is not compatible with the rest of the code. Is there any other way to group values monthly without using `groupby`?

This is what I've written:

```py
monthly_vol['mDate'] = monthly_vol.index.to_period("M")
monthly_vol = monthly_vol.groupby(['mDate'])
print(monthly_vol)
```

Comment: can you share input and expected output.

Comment: You can use [pd.Grouper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55559374/11380795)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.